# Why can't I ping myself in chat?

Tags: support, feature-request, chat

I'm trying to ping myself in chat but I can't. Is there any way we can add this feature? It would help me organize my thoughts in the chat.

Thanks.

Comment: The point of @-pings to to grab the attention of another user.  Why is the world would you need to grab your own attention?  I can't see any possible use for the ability to ping oneself...

Comment: I hear music when I want to organize my thoughts. My recommendation (I like for example), the melody *Xpandau* by Lorenz Rhode from the official channel **Dirt Crew Recordings** of  YouTube.

Answer (score 5):

In chat, you can "link" to a previous comment by beginning a comment with the text

```
:[comment id]
```

The `[comment id]` is a number which uniquely identifies the comment in chat, and can be found by examining the "Permalink" URL.  For example, [this comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46361683#46361683) can be found at the URL `https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46361683#46361683`.  The `[comment id]` is that last number, `46361683`.  You can reply to that by entering

`:46361683 This is a reply to geocalc33's comment.`

into chat.  The result is something like the following (from my point of view; geocalc33 should see the same thing with some highligting):

[image]

Note that if you want to reply to something that someone else said, this process is much easier.  If you hover over a comment left by someone else, a little down-pointing triangle will appear on the left.  Click that, then click "reply to this message" to automatically append the appropriate `:[comment id]` text to the beginning of your comment.

[image]

Comment: I will add that something like that can be occasionally useful. The ping basically can be ignored - I am already aware that I posted the message, so it does not really matter that I am notified about this But in this way I get also a little arrow at the beginning of the message - this might be useful for other users reading the message; in this way they get to see the context and they can easily find the message for which this is a follow-up.

Comment: @MartinSleziak  But when I use this mode of updating an earlier comment of mine, using the method described above, and then hear a ping, I end up almost always checking the chats I'm in to see if someone pinged me.  Then I remember, using the work around above, one pings oneself.